# How to get id from sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a problems, with get an id of user. I can get name, email, created_at columns, but i cannot get id. Help please.

```
public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL +  " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String name, String email,  String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(3));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

    return user;
}

/**
 * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void deleteUsers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
}`
```

Result of fetch:

> D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {name=admin,
>   created_at=2020-05-06 22:04:39, email=admin@gmail.com}

Comment: and what is `cursor.getLong(0)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column indices of the `Cursor` object are `0` based, so the index of the column `KEY_ID` is `0` and you do not add it to the `HashMap`.
Change to this:

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    user.put(KEY_ID, cursor.getString(0));
    user.put(KEY_NAME, cursor.getString(1));
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, cursor.getString(2));
    user.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, cursor.getString(3));
}
```

It's better to use the `KEY_???` constants throughout your code.
Also instead of the column indices `0,1,2...` use the method `getColumnIndex()`:

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    user.put(KEY_ID, cursor.getString(getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
    user.put(KEY_NAME, cursor.getString(getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, cursor.getString(getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
    user.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, cursor.getString(getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for you response. But, i already add `user.put(KEY_ID, cursor.getString(0));` and id that i get is 1 in all events.

Comment: This is because you add only 1 row to the HashMap.

Comment: Yes, in this code, that i send, i add only Name, email, and created_at. But before i already add it. And now, when i add KEY_ID like your answer, i have id=1 in all cases.

Comment: As I said your query may return many rows but your code uses **only the 1st row** which adds to the HashMap. You don't use the other rows of the table.

Comment: But why i get a correct email, created_at, name columns and only id is incorrect? Sorry for my stpd question. But i don't understand your answer

Comment: (1) you did not post the code that uses the method `getUserDetails()` and (2) I don't have the data of your table, so I can't say if you get the wrong id (which is impossible if you use the code correctly). My answer is about the question as you posted it, meaning why you don't get the id in the results. If you have a different requirement you can post a new question.

Comment: Just set AUTO_INCREMENT for id field so u will get incremented id. And on adding record, do not pass the value of id field.